# svclog file is not being generated

Tags: web-services, wcf, web-config, svc

Been wasting a full day arround this problem.
This had never happen to me before.

My service is working in an Azure machine.

I'm trying to generate a .svclog file to trace whats causing my ios app not being able to login on https, but the svclog file is not being generated.

I tried to use fiddler to capture the requests but i get nothing when i try to login by the app.

If I try to use the app with http address im able to login but the svclog is also not generated.

If I use tcptrace i can see a request and an answer but it is encrypted.

I have given permissions to "Everyone" on the folder at c:\logs\

any idea what i might be missing here? is there some sort of pre requirement to make the tracer work

This is my system diagnostics in web.Config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="c:\logs\myMessages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="messagelistener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
    name="xmlTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```